# Scaling Images in Visualforce PDFs

Tags: visualforce, pdf

In our org, users are able to create PDFs with a logo in the header. We're using renderAs="pdf" to achieve this. The problem is we can't control the dimensions of the logos, so we need to scale them appropriately when we render the page. Here's what I've tried:

```
  <style>
        .headerLogo{
            max-height:100px; 
            max-width:200px; 
        }
  </style>

  <div class="header">
        <div>
            <img class="headerLogo" src="{!imageURL}"/>
        </div>
  </div>
```

When I don't render the page as a PDF this works great, but once i render as a PDF, the logo just expands to its original size. Is max-height/max-width supported in the Salesforce PDF generator?

Comment: Are these images a known ratio or could they be pretty much anything?

Comment: Unfortunately they can be pretty much anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the "What about embedded images? Are images downscaled?" section of [The Flying Saucer User's Guide](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html) (the technology usually assumed to generate PDF in Salesforce):

> For intrinsic width/height calculations we assume a resolution of 96
>   DPI, but setting an explicit width/height makes it possible to use an
>   arbitrary DPI.

In repositories such as https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer there isn't obvious evidence that the `max-height` and `max-width` are supported for images. So try `width` or `height` instead in your CSS.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't know the dimensions of the logos since Users can choose their own logos, so if I set width/height it may distort the images. I want to use max-width/max-height so that that I can make sure the picture is not distorted and so it fits in the header.

Comment: @Sean Just set the width or the height; the other dimension should scale in proportion. But not a perfect solution. And tell your users what sizes are required/recommended/allowed.

Comment: Yeah I figured that would be the best I could get. Setting just the width causes issues with tall skinny images, and just the height causes issues with short fat images. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Sean There is mention in this thread [word-wrap not working with VisualForce PDF generation?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45422/word-wrap-not-working-with-visualforce-pdf-generation) of the PDF engine changing in the future so eventually this problem might be solved.