# Visualforce Render as PDF image not scaling down

Tags: visualforce

I want the image, regardless of original size to scale down into a max width of 300px or 60% of the table width.  I've tried every suggestion I can find online and the image does not scale down.  Code below.

```
<apex:page renderAs="PDF" standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="true" applyHtmlTag="true">
    <html>


    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="author" content="Patrick Lawson" />
        <style type="text/css">

            img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            }

            table {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <apex:repeat value="{!Opportunity.Client_Reports__r}" var="report">

            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; height:200px; margin-bottom: 20px;">

                <tr style="vertical-align: bottom;">
                    <td style="width:20%; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 12pt;  font-weight: bold; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center; text-decoration: underline;">Setting Type
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:60%; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;">
                    <apex:image url="{!report.Public_Image_URL__c}" style="max-wiidth:300px;max-height:300px;"/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 20%; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold; vertical-align: bottom; text-align: center;">Licensed Capacity
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <td rowspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Facility_Type__c   }" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center; font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #4169E1;">{!report.Facility_Name__c}
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="4" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;">{!report.Licensed_Capacity__c}
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;">{!report.Facility_Address__c}
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 12pt; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;">{!report.Distance__c} Distance From
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center;font-family: Georgia, serif; font-size: 12pt;">{!report.Client__r.Best_Address__Street__s}, {!report.Client__r.Best_Address__City__s}, {!report.Client__r.Best_Address__StateCode__s}, {!report.Client__r.Best_Address__PostalCode__s}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                
            </table> 

            <br></br>

            <table style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; border-spacing: 0;height:600px">

                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: bottom;text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Availability_Icon__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: bottom;text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Financials_Icon__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: bottom;text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Online_Search_Icon__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: bottom;text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Staffing_Icon__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: bottom;text-align: center;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Inspection_History_Icon__c}" /></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff; margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: top;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Facility_Available_Accommidations__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td style="background-color:  #e6f2ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: top;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Finances__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: top;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Socials__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td style="background-color:  #e6f2ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: top;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.Staffing__c}" /></span></td>
                    <td rowspan="3" colspan="1" style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; vertical-align: top;"><span style="padding: 0; margin: 0;"><apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!report.License_Records__c}" /></span></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-bottom: -1px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">Facility Notes</td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-bottom: -1px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">{!report.Facility_Notes__c}</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-bottom: -1px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">CareWise Notes</td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="background-color:   #e6e6ff;margin-bottom: -1px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">{!report.CareWise_Notes__c}</td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </apex:repeat>

        </body>

    </html>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: Just to double check, is the max-width style spelt correctly in your code? The snippet you've provided in your question has 'max-wiidth' in the style attribute for the apex:image block.

Comment: Check this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47747/scaling-images-in-visualforce-pdfs. It seems the underlying PDF rendering engine doesn't support max-width and max-height.