# Text label rotation is not working when exporting to pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce

I need to rotate the text while exporting to pdf. The same this is working fine in the html page. The css to rotate the text is not working as expected.
Please help...

Comment: Can you provide your code please ?

Comment: Please find the code:                  #rot
{
 -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);    
}

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce's current PDF generation is commonly assumed to be based on [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) which only claims to support CSS 2.1 and rotate is part of CSS 3. Not all styling that works in your browser will work in the PDF output.

There is mention of a future improved PDF renderer in one of the answers to [word-wrap not working with VisualForce PDF generation?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45422/word-wrap-not-working-with-visualforce-pdf-generation). So perhaps in a future Salesforce release the PDF rendering will be more capable.

Comment: Without providing any specifics, there's also mention of improvements to rendering PDFs in the Winter 15 release notes.

Comment: as if this function thus far is  still not in work!