# Visualforce renderas pdf text rotation

Tags: visualforce, css, renderas

I have created visualforce page which will be render as pdf. 
In that I tried using transform:rotate(90deg); and writing-mode: vertical-rl; it's working fine in visualforce page but when renderas pdf mentioned css for text rotation is not applied.

```
<apex:page controller="RenderController" renderAs="pdf" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <html>
        <body>
        <p style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;position: absolute;right: 35px;float: none;top: 50%;margin: 0;"> PT001-2018 © Candor Renting de Equipamentos S.A </p>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: This is not supported. Although I don't have any link for this.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178572/visualforce-renderas-pdf-not-supporting-slds-css?rq=1 Similar issue here with some details

Comment: Maybe this will help.https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51975/text-label-rotation-is-not-working-when-exporting-to-pdf

Comment: Assuming you only want that specific sentence rotated than as a simple work around you could put the text in an image and use that image instead.

Comment: Is it not possible without image in static resource?

Comment: It is probably possible, but it is probably not worth your time and effort to build it. One option that comes to mind is using svg's to render your text. I have no idea if flying saucer supports that though.

Comment: Yup, the render engine only supports CSS 2.1 and HTML 4.2. You're not going to get any dynamic content to render to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Even moving to stylesheet to static resource didn't make the text to rotate. Since the visualforce engine didn't render the CSS to rotate the text. I created a vertical text with Ms Power point.

- Took the screenshot of the same.
- Used it as a image to display the vertical text in visualforce page rendered as PDF

`<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf" sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <html>
        <body>
        <div style="writing-mode: vertical-rl;position: absolute;right: 35px;float: none;top: 50%;margin: 0;">
        <img src="{!$Resource.vertical_text}"/>

        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>`