# Long Text Area not rendering correctly when rendered as pdf

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I have an issue where I have a VF page containing a long text area field.  The field and data displays correctly when it's a standard VF page.  I have an option to view the page as a PDF and when perform this logic the field cuts off data on the view.

Is there anything special I need to do to get this to render correctly in the PDF view?  I'm using the apex:outputField to display the data on both the VF page and PDF page.

[image: view in vf page]

[image: View as pdf]

Comment: Take a look at this question, information here might be helpful... http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/45422/word-wrap-not-working-with-visualforce-pdf-generation/45488#45488

Comment: Have you tried setting standardStyleSheets = "False"? All I ever have to use is the output field so maybe you have some other CSS causing it to not display properly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to SF.SE Bolt. `<apex: outputField>` is considered an unsafe component to use when rendering a PDF. See [Best Practices for Rendering PDFs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_additional_render_pdf.htm) to learn which ones can and cannot be safely used.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out for me.  I didn't realize the apex:output field was unsafe to use in pdf rendering.